# Three.js: create a square cone with radius segments more than 4

Tags: three.js

I have done some math to create a square cone with radius segment
more than 4. When the top and bottom radius are the same it works fine as shown in the image.
[image: top and bottom radius are the same]

but when the top and bottom radius are different it does not work as shown in the image.
[image: top and bottom radius are not the same]

I am not sure what the problem is? I really appreciate any other way to do this? Thank you in advance. here is my code:

```
<html>

<head>

<title>Lightshade</title>


<script src="three.js"> </script>
<script src="TrackballControls.js"></script>


</head>

<body>

<script>

//declaring variables
var camera, scene, renderer;
var controls;
var cone, coneGeometry;

scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera( -window.innerWidth /  2.5, window.innerWidth / 2.5, window.innerHeight / 2.5, -window.innerHeight /  2.5, -10000, 1000000);

camera.position.set( 0, 2.0, 5.0);
camera.lookAt(scene.position);  

//adding the renderer to the screen
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true} );
renderer.setClearColor( 0xeeeeee , 0); //eeeeee
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
renderer.shadowMapCullFace = THREE.CullFaceBack;
renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;

document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

//adding the camera interactive method
controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
controls.noKeys = true;


//creating materials for lightshade
lightshadeMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color:0xffeb00,wireframe:false, side:THREE.DoubleSide, ambient: 0xffffff});

var coneGeometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 50, 125, 150, 60, 44 , true);
var cone = new THREE.Mesh( coneGeometry, lightshadeMaterial );
cone.geometry.applyMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationY(Math.PI/2));  



for (j=0;j<=2684;j=j+61) {
    for (i=0;i<=60;i++) { 

        if (i<=15) {

            tempLineGrad = (cone.geometry.vertices[15].z - cone.geometry.vertices[0].z) / (cone.geometry.vertices[15].x - cone.geometry.vertices[0].x);
            cone.geometry.vertices[i+j].z = tempLineGrad * (cone.geometry.vertices[i+j].x - cone.geometry.vertices[0].x) + cone.geometry.vertices[0].z;
        }
        if (i>15 && i<=30){
            tempLineGrad = (cone.geometry.vertices[30].z - cone.geometry.vertices[15].z) / (cone.geometry.vertices[30].x - cone.geometry.vertices[15].x);

            if (tempLineGrad>999999) {

                cone.geometry.vertices[i+j].x = cone.geometry.vertices[15].x;

            } else {
            cone.geometry.vertices[i+j].z = tempLineGrad * (cone.geometry.vertices[i+j].x - cone.geometry.vertices[15].x) + cone.geometry.vertices[15].z;
            }
        }
        if (i>30 && i<=45){
            tempLineGrad = (cone.geometry.vertices[45].z - cone.geometry.vertices[30].z) / (cone.geometry.vertices[45].x - cone.geometry.vertices[30].x);
            cone.geometry.vertices[i+j].z = tempLineGrad * (cone.geometry.vertices[i+j].x - cone.geometry.vertices[30].x) +  cone.geometry.vertices[30].z;
        }
        if (i>45 && i<=60){
            tempLineGrad = (cone.geometry.vertices[60].z - cone.geometry.vertices[45].z) / (cone.geometry.vertices[60].x - cone.geometry.vertices[45].x);
            cone.geometry.vertices[i+j].z = tempLineGrad * (cone.geometry.vertices[i+j].x - cone.geometry.vertices[45].x) +  cone.geometry.vertices[45].z;

        }
    }
}
scene.add(cone);

// adding some light to the screen
var light3 = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 1, 1000); 
light3.position.set( 0, 300.0, 0 ); 
scene.add( light3 );        

var light1 = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff,0.7, 1000  ); 
light1.position.set( 0, 4.0, 0 ); 
scene.add( light1 );
var light2 = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 0.7, 1000  ); 
light2.position.set( 0, -1.0, 0 ); 
scene.add( light2 );

var light4 = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 1, 1000); 
light4.position.set( 300.0, 160.0, 300.0 ); 
scene.add( light4 );

var light5 = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 1, 1000); 
light5.position.set( -300.0, 160.0, 300.0 ); 
scene.add( light5 );




function animate() {
requestAnimationFrame(animate);

render();
}

function render() {


controls.update();

renderer.render( scene, camera );
}

animate();



</script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Tip: see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17558085/three-js-orthographic-camera/17567292#17567292} for how to properly instantiate an orthographic camera.

Comment: Thank you very much. I corrected that but it seems that the problem is from somewhere else.