# three.js Particles closer to camera appears larger in Orthographic Camera

Tags: three.js

It seems that with `OrthographicCamera`, if a particle (`Points`) is closer to the camera it will just appear to be larger. While, for example, `BoxGeometry`s with same size will always be in the same size, regardless of their distances to the camera.

See the sample below, where the green & red cubes have the same size but different distances to camera, so do the two white particles:

```js
var container, camera, controls, scene, renderer;
init();
animate();

function init() {
  var container = document.getElementById('container');

  camera =
    new THREE.OrthographicCamera(-window.innerWidth / 2,
      window.innerWidth / 2, -window.innerHeight / 2,
      window.innerHeight / 2, 1, 400);
  camera.position.z = 200;

  controls = new THREE.OrthographicTrackballControls(camera);
  controls.addEventListener('change', render);

  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight()
  light.position.set(1, 5, 10)
  scene.add(light);
  var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xaaaaaa)
  light.position.set(-10, -1, -5)
  scene.add(light);
  var light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x555555)
  scene.add(light);

  var pGeo = new THREE.Geometry()
  var pVec1 = new THREE.Vector3
  var pVec2 = new THREE.Vector3
  var a = 80
  pGeo.vertices.push(pVec1.fromArray([-a, -a, -a]));
  pGeo.vertices.push(pVec2.fromArray([a, a, a]));
  scene.add(new THREE.Points(pGeo, new THREE.PointsMaterial({
    size: 80
  })))

  var cGeo = new THREE.BoxGeometry(80, 80, 80);
  var MPG1 = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: 0xff0000
  });
  var cMesh1 = new THREE.Mesh(cGeo, MPG1);
  cMesh1.position.set(a, -a, -a);
  cMesh1.updateMatrix();
  scene.add(cMesh1);
  var MPG2 = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: 0x00ff00
  });
  var cMesh2 = new THREE.Mesh(cGeo, MPG2);
  cMesh2.position.set(-a, a, a);
  cMesh2.updateMatrix();
  scene.add(cMesh2);

  // renderer
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
  renderer.render(scene, camera)
  render()
}

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  controls.update();
}

function render() {
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```html
<script src="http://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrthographicTrackballControls.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Particle_Orthographic</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

I want to know, whether there is something I missed that can make particles behave in the same way as other `Geometry` with `OrthographicCamera`.

Because I am trying to visualise some aluminum matrix, `OrthographicCamera` is quite necessary to demonstrate the uniform crystal structure. Also the matrix would vary from 4^3 to 100^3 in volume (and number of aluminum atoms), so the `scene` will sort of keep changing size, and other `Geometry` will make it very slow.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17558085/three-js-orthographic-camera/17567292#17567292 so you instantiate your orthographic camera with the proper units. Try `PointsMaterial.sizeAttenuation = false;`

Comment: @WestLangley Thank you! `sizeAttenuation` works! Sorry didn't read the API carefully. But then I just got another question: the space between particles would get zoomed but not their size (even `setZoom`), different to other `Geometry`. Is this the nature of "cheap" `PointsMaterial`? Though I can workaround it with dynamically changing particle size now with `sizeAttenuation: false`. And would you mind add your comment as answer as it is the answer.

Comment: @WestLangley but in `PerspectiveCamera` zooming on particles works fine (with `TrackballControls`).

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your comments. Please post a new question if you need additional help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `THREE.PointsMaterial`, to prevent the particle size from attenuating (changing size) with distance from the camera, set

```
material.sizeAttenuation = false;
```

three.js r.72