# Is positive Z axis going inward in threejs? Camera.near and camera.far behaves funny

Tags: javascript, three.js, orthographic

I'm trying to render only slice of my 3d object. In orthographic camera I want camera.near as 2.0 and camera.far as 1.5 then iterate and give camera.near = 1.5 and camera.far = 1.0. And so on. But it is not working. When I pass smaller value(2) to camera.near and larger value (10) to camera.far it kind of works. But I want just the opposite. I thought Z axis is coming outward from the screen.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17558085/three-js-orthographic-camera/17567292#17567292

Comment: @WestLangley so camera.near and camera.far should be positive values. But how should we pass values if z is from 2 to -2? camera.near should be 2 and should camera.far be 2 + depth? And suppose i have to slice from z =0 to z = -2 then camera.near will be 0 and camera.far will be 0 + depth? (my depth value will be something like 0.5)

Comment: To avoid seeing objects behind the camera, `near` and `far` need to be positive. Always, `near < far`.

Comment: @WestLangley Got it. Thanks

Comment: @WestLangley Its not working. my camera is at (0,0,5) and I want to render from z = 2 to z = -2. I'm stepping by 0.4. How should I assign my camera.near and camera.far values or how should i write my loop? I tried getting distance from camera.position.z to z farthest value of my model( -2). and tried rendering both from front to back and back to front and its not working. Would you be able to tell me how should i write my loop?

Comment: Your best bet is to make a new post and ask the community if you need help with your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The z axis in Three.js is positive coming "out."

[image]

HOWEVER: the reason things can seem funny is that when you are setting view matrices, you actually specify the near/far planes as **distance from the viewer.**  This is from the [OpenGL spec](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glOrtho.xml):

> **Parameters**
>
> *nearVal, farVal* 
> Specify the distances to the nearer and farther depth
> clipping planes. These values are negative if the plane is to be
> behind the viewer.

FYI when you are using a perspective matrix, both values are always positive.

Comment: If I have to go from z = 2 to -2 then should it be like this.                           for (var i = minMax.zMax ; i > minMax.zMin; i = i-voxelDepth){
 camera.near = i ;
 camera.far = i + voxelDepth;
   
 camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
 renderer.render( scene, camera );

}