# CSS3D renderer with Orthographic camera canvas origin changing?

Tags: javascript, three.js

When changing the camera from perspective to orthographic, the cameras position also seem to change so that 0,0,0 is located in the top left hand corner.

Is this behaviour correct?

See [Example](http://codepen.io/BuildingJarl/pen/jWPNZz?editors=001)

## Orthographic

```
var h = window.innerHeight;
var w = window.innerWidth;

var viewSize = h;
var aspectRatio = w/h; //1 unit should be one pixel
var left = (-aspectRatio * viewSize) / 2;
var right = (aspectRatio * viewSize) / 2;
var top = viewSize / 2;
var bottom = -viewSize / 2;
var near = 1;
var far = 100;

camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera( left, right, top, bottom, near, far );
```

[image: Ortho]

## Perspective

```
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
camera.position.z = 500;
```

[image: Perspective]

Comment: FYI, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17558085/three-js-orthographic-camera/17567292#17567292 for a discussion regarding `OrthographicCamera` units.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CSS3DRenderer` does not support `OrthographicCamera`.

three.js r.73

Comment: It is supported from `three.js r.92`. more info https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/11534