# Three.js, rotate camera around center

Tags: javascript, three.js

Got some problems regarding OrbitControls and rotation.

I´m using OrbitControls but cant seem to get the camera to rotate around the "new" center after panning.

Hoping for some help in the right direction!

Using orthographic camera based on the following example. 
https://threejs.org/examples/misc_controls_orbit.html

Im creating the controls as follows:

```
controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
controls.enableDamping = true;
controls.dampingFactor = 0.25;
```

Here´s an code example [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4q1mLt1u/).

Thanks in advance!
//Robert

Comment: Can you put up a fiddle or a sample of your modified code?

Comment: 1. Looks like it is working to me. You will have to explain in more detail what you think is not working. 2. Unrelated, but you need to read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17558085/three-js-orthographic-camera/17567292#17567292) about how to properly instantiate an orthographic camera.